# Dissociating NSPasteboardItem from pasteboard

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, exception, nspasteboard

What I am trying to do on a high level is store the current data that is on the pasteboard (data of any type) using this code, which I believe to be correct:

```
- (NSArray *)readFromPasteBoard
{
    NSMutableArray *pasteboardItems = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSPasteboardItem *item in [pasteboard pasteboardItems]) {
        //Create new data holder
        NSPasteboardItem *dataHolder = [[NSPasteboardItem alloc] init];
        //For each type in the pasteboard's items
        for (NSString *type in [item types]) {
            //Get each type's data and add it to the new dataholder
            NSData *data = [[item dataForType:type] mutableCopy];
            if (data) {
                [dataHolder setData:data forType:type];
            }
        }
        [pasteboardItems addObject:dataHolder];
    }
    return pasteboardItems;
}
```

I then store `pasteboardItems` for later use. My problem is that when I try to write this same data to the pasteboard:

```
- (void)writeToPasteBoard:(NSArray *)objectsToWrite
{
    [pasteboard clearContents];
    [pasteboard writeObjects:objectsToWrite];
}
```

What I am doing is passing in an array with the `NSPasteboardItem` I made earlier. I then get this error:

```
Cannot write pasteboard item <NSPasteboardItem: 0x101a11540>.  It is already associated   
with another pasteboard.
```

I'm a little bit confused, because the `NSPasteboardItem` I am trying to write to the pasteboard isn't associated with any pasteboard as I instantiated it myself and never retrieved it from the pasteboard. Thanks for your help, please let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting that error on a second or subsequent call to `-writeToPasteboard:`? Maybe the first time succeeded silently and you didn't realize it.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I am getting this error on a subsequent call to writeToPasteboard. I don't know how I didn't notice this before. What would be the best/cleanest way to avoid this exception being raised due to a subsequent write of the same item? Thank you for your help

Comment: I think you have to make a new copy each time, just like you made the first.